# How can I read data from USB?

Tags: java, usb, inputstream, bulk

I got a question:
I found the libusb library for java, but I really don't understand how to read some data. There is a method called readBulk() or readInterrupt, but they have an int as return type.I don't know how to store the data, because the method only returns the actual number of bytes ,which the method had read. In the CommPort class supports a method called getInputStream(), this method uses an InputStream as return type and so I can do something with that data.

Comment: it'd be generally useful to say what OS and platform you're using. The tags suggest it's java, but since you don't actually say so...

Comment: Sorry yes I use java on Windows.

Comment: You need to have some idea of what type of data your device is going to generate. USB is all host initiated, so you have to know what it is you are asking for from the device. I'd suggest reading [USB Complete](http://www.amazon.com/USB-Complete-Developers-Guide-Guides/dp/1931448086) to learn more about USB in general, then ask a more specific question.